# Allowing MDM users to not only enroll devices (/mydevices) but also assign them to certain groups?

Tags: ios, server.app, mobile-device-management

So I would love to allow one of our users access to not only add their own devices (as they do now by going to server/mydevices), but also decide which group the device should belong to.

The user has 3 different types of devices all which should belong in separate groups. As of now we allow the user to add the device using Apple Configurator or by going to the mydevices interface and enrolling it directly from the device, but after that there's no way for them to specify that the device should end up in a certain device group.

Is there any way to allow the user to select a group for the device to go into? Or if not, is there any way to set it so that all devices for a certain user goes into a specific device group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out there is no way to do this now. At least as far as I've been able to tell.